# Why is a bool taking 7 bytes of memory?

Tags: swift, swift-playground, memory-layout

I was studying about Swift Memory Layout using a Xcode Playground, and I created a struct with a bool, a double and an int32, as shown below. Based on this structure, the print result of the MemoryLayout should be 13, but it's printing 20 instead. Any ideas why? Maybe I'm missing something. Thanks!

```
struct SampleStruct { //0
    var bool: Bool = true //1
    var double: Double = 1 //8
    var int32: Int32 = 122 //4
}

MemoryLayout<SampleStruct>.size //Should print 13, but prints 20
```

Comment: Never test memory or performance in a playground. Test it in a real app project set to release mode.

Comment: You'll find the precise alignment and padding rules in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI/TypeLayout.rst.

Comment: Change the order to double, int32, bool and observe how the size changes!

Comment: I did @MartinR. It worked! not sure why though. I'll take a look in this GitHub repo you sent.

Answer (score 4):

> Based on this structure, the print result of the MemoryLayout should be 13, but it's printing 20 instead. Any ideas why?

Processors generally like larger types to be aligned to boundaries that match their bus size. That double in your struct is 8 bytes long, and the 64-bit processor you're compiling for can read that in one operation if it's stored at an address that's a multiple of 8, so that's where the compiler puts it.

https://swiftunboxed.com/internals/size-stride-alignment/

Comment: I know, but if I followed your logic properly, it should print size 13 (two slots of 8 bytes, given that it can still get every element with 1 access), and stride 16. But the size was 20 and the stride 24.

Comment: @gabrielrf97 the compiler doesn't reorder fields, as this might affect certain aspects of the code, there is 1 byte used for the Boolean, 7 bytes for padding, 8 bytes for the double and 4 for the float

Comment: @gabrielrf97 You're missing the point about alignment. Because of the way the processor's memory bus is wired up to RAM, the processor *can't* read a full-width value in one operation if the value isn't aligned to the right boundary. E.g. a processor with a 64-bit bus reads 8 bytes at a time, and it does those reads from addresses 0, 8, 16, 24, etc. If you put a 1-byte bool at address 0 followed by the 8-byte double at address 1, the processor has to first read bytes 0-7, and then read 8-16, and then shift the first value over 8 bits and tack on the byte from address 8.

Comment: The reason that reordering the fields changes the size is that the 4-byte int doesn't have to be on an 8-byte boundary: if you change the order from `bool, double, int` to `bool, int, double` you don't need as much padding to get the values aligned properly. You get something like `bpppiiiidddddddd` instead of `bpppppppddddddddiii` (where b is bool, i is int, d is double, p is padding).

Comment: I've read this post you've sent the link @Caled. Very good! Thanks for the answer, now I get it.

Comment: Also thanks @Ferrybig for the comment, I've taken a look at ABI Contract too, and apparently that's not going to change. I assumed the compiler reorganised the variables to make the optimal match, but it doesn't and it will never do.

Comment: The link was actually added by @springborn, but I agree that it adds a lot more helpful background info.